# ¿Por qué mi index.php no quiere reconocer el código de CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

tengo un problema. Estos haciendo una Landing page y voy a incrustar código php, solamente para atraer la información de un formularios y hacer unos procedimientos. Es la primera vez que hago un proyecto con index.php y por supuesto lleva código css, pero el problema es que ya llevo días que hago diversas modificaciones en la hoja de css, pero al momento de actualizar con F5 no sucede nada, las anteriores modificaciones no se modifican. Ahora, hago otra pestaña de css, copio, pego, lo enlazo y funciona. Sin embargo, de rato hago otras modificaciones y ya no vuelve funcionar.

¿Qué puedo hacer? Cuando la extensión es con HTML (index.html) nunca tengo este problema, pero con PHP sí.

PD. No me marca ningún error en ningún lado.

Comment: Probaste CTRL+F5 en chrome?

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez ¿Tiene que ver con navegadores? Para testear uso FireFox

Comment: Lo que describes parece claramente un problema de cache.  solo con presionar f5 no se borra el cache. en chrome debes presionar ctrl + f5. solo asegurate de actualizar borrando el cache.

Comment: Como bien dicen todos, probablemente sea un problema de cache. Lo que podés hacer es modificar la URL del archivo CSS después de hacer modificaciones, eso va a hacer que no levante lo que está en cache. Por ejemplo, si la ruta es `/estilos.css`, podés cambiarla a `estilos.css?v=1`, luego `estilos.css?v=2`, con agregar cualquier parámetro es suficiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aveces la cache de los navegadores quedan guardados por página y lo que debes hacer es probar con CRTL + SHIFT + R.
Si no funciona asi debes borrar la cache de la página Index.php para que cargue desde cero con el css.

Comment: Este fue el comentario que más me ayudó. Si funciona esa combinación de teclas, aunque es verdad lo que me dijeron el resto; el problema fue la caché. Lo he eliminado y ha funcionado correctamente. Muchísimas gracias a todos, siempre con su ayuda.